# ayuda suma-resta-división-multiplicacion

Tags: javascript, html

Encontre este codigo y lo adapte a lo q necesito pero no coincide al momento de hacer la division multiplicacion y resta, no se q estoy haciendo mal:
ejemplo en total del 1 al 7 le pongo valor de 2, al sumar da 14 ahora en el iva seria mi resultado de total(valor8) deberia de darme 2.24 y me da 1.92, esos 14 le resto los 2.24 deberia de darme en total(totalNeto) = 11.76 y me imprime 10.4 en que estoy mal , como q al momento de tomar el (valor 8, la suma) no lo toma bien.

```
function sumar()
    {
        var valor1=verificar("total1");
        var valor2=verificar("total2");
        var valor3=verificar("total3");
        var valor4=verificar("total4");
        var valor5=verificar("total5");
        var valor6=verificar("total6");
        var valor7=verificar("total7");
        var valor8=verificar("total");
        var valor9=verificar("iva");
        var multiplica=16;
        var dividir = 100;
        // realizamos la suma de los valores y los ponemos en la casilla del
        // formulario que contiene el total
        document.getElementById("total").value=parseFloat(valor1)+parseFloat(valor2)+parseFloat(valor3)+parseFloat(valor4)+parseFloat(valor5)+parseFloat(valor6)+parseFloat(valor7);

        document.getElementById("iva").value=parseFloat(valor8)*parseFloat(multiplica)/parseFloat(dividir);
        document.getElementById("totalNeto").value=parseFloat(valor8)-parseFloat(valor9);
    }
```

Verificar.

```
function verificar(id)
    {
        var obj=document.getElementById(id);
        if(obj.value=="")
            value="0";
        else
            value=obj.value;
        if(validate_importe(value,1))
        {
            // marcamos como erroneo
            obj.style.borderColor="#808080";
            return value;
        }else{
            // marcamos como erroneo
            obj.style.borderColor="#f00";
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Validar importe.

```
function validate_importe(value,decimal)
    {
        if(decimal==undefined)
            decimal=0;

        if(decimal==1)
        {
            // Permite decimales tanto por . como por ,
            var patron=new RegExp("^[0-9]+((,|\.)[0-9]{1,2})?$");
        }else{
            // Numero entero normal
            var patron=new RegExp("^([0-9])*$")
        }

        if(value && value.search(patron)==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código de la función verificar? Asumo que simplemente leer los valores de los inputs con el ID dado como parámetro, pero para confirmar el error (pista: estás leyendo "total" antes de cambiarle el valor con el resultado de la suma)

Comment: Pon un `debugger` en las líneas de las que sospechas para que veas en el depurador los valores que tienes en esas líneas. Si usas un editor como VSCode puedes depurar el código desde allí.

Comment: Listo gracias ya pude resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás calculando los valores en los tiempo incorrectos. Estás asumiendo que la variable **valor8** te está quedando con el total que calculaste más abajo con esta línea:

```
document.getElementById("total").value=parseFloat(valor1)+parseFloat(valor2)+parseFloat(valor3)+parseFloat(valor4)+parseFloat(valor5)+parseFloat(valor6)+parseFloat(valor7);
```

Realmente aunque lograste actualizar la página con el valor total la variable **valor8** no tomó este valor por que nunca se lo asignaste, es decir está línea se llamó antes de calcular el valor total, por lo tanto el valor que tomó es otro:

```
var valor8=verificar("total");
```

Te sugiero hacer los cálculos primero en las variables de la función y una vez tengas todos los valores ahí si actualizar la página con los resultados. Supongo estás haciendo esta prueba en el navegador, con el inspector del mismo puedes hacer debug del javascript.

Comment: gracias amigo, ya pude resolver el problema